# How to display the WMS layer . If Server not geoserver

Tags: openlayers, arcgis, geoserver

How to display the WMS layer if the server is not Geoserver.

Example this WMS URL from [this link](https://data.go.id/dataset?res_format=wms%20http://portal.ina-sdi.or.id/arcgis/rest/services/IGD/RupabumiIndonesia/MapServer).

Comment: Hi there @antochoy there is info on connecting 
OpenLayers to MapServer over at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/arcgis-tiled.html

Comment: With MapServer. GeoServer is easier to handle. MapServer provides more possibilities but need you to code a bit.

Answer (score 3):

**You Can Use ARCGIS Url To Show the Tile Layer of That Url **

> Openlayers 4.5

```
  var layers = [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
      source: new ol.source.TileArcGISRest({
        url: https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer
      })
    })
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, this is your WMS link @antochoy:

http://portal.ina-sdi.or.id/arcgis/services/IGD/RupabumiIndonesia/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

For the map part, try this (It works, I included your your layer named "2" only):

```
var layers = [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  }),
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    extent: [94.972663,-11.007615,141.029973,6.076940],
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: 'http://portal.ina-sdi.or.id/arcgis/services/IGD/RupabumiIndonesia/MapServer/WMSServer',
      params: {'LAYERS': '2', 'TILED': true},
      projection: 'EPSG:4326'
    })
  })
];
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: layers,
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [106,0],
    zoom: 6,
    projection: 'EPSG:4326'
  })
});
```